# Install Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS without losing Windows 7 bootloader

Tags: 14.04, grub2, windows-7, bootloader, mbr

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS alongside with Windows 7.

But there is one issue that if I install Ubuntu, I will lose Windows 7 bootloader and it will replace GRUB bootloader instead of Windows 7 bootloader with black screen.

**Brief description what I did before:**

I have tried to install Ubuntu with this way and I lost my Windows 7 bootloader 2 days ago. Then I panicked and removed the partition of Ubuntu in Windows 7 and when I restarted PC it showed black error screen with grubrescue command line. I inserted Windows 7 installation disk and restored Windows 7 bootloader from command line with `bootrec` command.

**What I want to do now:**

Now I want to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 and also to have Windows 7 bootloader with two OS options: Windows 7 and Ubuntu. What I should do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On installation, choose the **Soomething else** option to open the advanced partitioning tool.

Make a separate partition for `/boot` (500 MB in size is enough):

[image: boot partition]

and another one for root:

[image: Ubuntu partition]

You can make a separate partition for `/home` for your data and settings and also one for *swap* if you want to use hibernation on Ubuntu.

Before continuing to install, you must choose the boot partition as the bootloader. On the screenshot below it's on `/dev/sda5`.

[image: bootloader]

After the installation got completed you won't see Ubuntu on the Windows bootloader and your Winodws will boot as usual. Then, you can use EasyBCD grub editor on Windows to add Ubuntu to its bootloader.

[image: EasyBCD]

**Read more detailed procedure on [how to dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/).**

Comment: so, I have to install Ubuntu to separate partition, for example, /dev/sda6, and then I need to use EasyBCD on Windows to repair bootloader?

Comment: You must have at least 2 partitions for Ubuntu, one as root for `/` and another for `/boot` and if your `/boot` partition is on, for example, /dev/sda6 you have to select it for Uuntu bootloader from drop-down on installation. I'll try to edit my answer in order to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVppdkOThCs

It is an easy way to boot Ubuntu on an existing windows computer, to try, and very easy to remove it if you don't like it after trying it.

Comment: Unfortunately, Wubi Installer is not supported by Ubuntu any more.